# Pop OS! No screen after suspend mode

Tags: linux, nvidia, graphics, suspend, pop-os

I installed Pop OS! to my PC with a win 10. Everything worked fine... But i wanted to set my PC to suspend mode, and then it was OK. But i tried to log in, but it was no screen... (All peripherals were lit. The PC started.) Whats this actually? I had to push the reset button....

Information:

```
OS: Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS x86_64
Host: B250M-DS3H
Kernel: 5.15.15-76051515-generic
Uptime: 4 mins
Packages: 2061 (dpkg), 4 (flatpak)
Shell: bash 5.0.17
Resolution: 1920x1080
DE: GNOME
WM: Mutter
WM Theme: Pop 
Theme: WhiteSur-dark-nord [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Numix-Circle [GTK2/3]
Terminal: gnome-terminal
CPU: Intel i5-7400 (4) @ 3.500GHz
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960
Memory: 2577MiB / 15963MiB
```

Thanks!

PS.: I'm absolutely a beginner in the Linux, maybe I won't understand everything....

Answer (score 0):

Same here. Usually can get by using ctr alt f# when this happens on other distros but on pop it won't take the bait.

This usually only happens to me when I call suspend manually.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/416573)